# How to add specific Field into output xml mapped by xstream

Tags: xstream, oxm

I have a POJO to be mapped into a XML. I m using XStream for that.

Eg:

```
class employee{
String name;
String age;
}
```

and corresponding XML will be,

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
<employees>
```

But my requiement is to have a DATE field along with the employee list for only one time at the begining. like this,

```
<employees>
  **<date>10/12/2015</date>**
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
<employees>
```

How to add a distinct element into the XStream generated XML. I have tried using a POJO with date and List of employees. The Date is getting printed several times like this,

```
<employees>
  **<date>10/12/2015</date>**
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
  **<date>10/12/2015</date>**
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
  **<date>10/12/2015</date>**
  <employee>
    <name></name>
    <age></age>
  </employee>
<employees>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually i solve this issue creating a container class.

i.e.:

```
@XStreamAlias("employees")
public class EmployeeList {

  @XStreamAlias("date")
  private Date date;

  @XStreamImplicit
  private List<Employee> employees;
}
```